# GUI hangs if i make requests and responses from HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have a c# win forms program to check if an URL exists or not.The program works fine but then when i start the process with the button click the gui hangs until the check is complete.I basically do a button click and execute the code below.Please help me on how to achieve the backgroundworker or other thread handling so that i can access my GUI.

// This is the Button i click and then my GUI hangs(Not accessible) until both the functions execute.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
            {
                performfetch();      
            }

    public void performfetch()
            {
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Visible = false;
                button1.Visible = false;
                progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                progressBar1.Maximum = int.Parse(label2.Text) - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(label2.Text); i++)
                {
                    string URL = dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString();
                    dataGridView1[1, i].Value = URLExists(URL);
                    progressBar1.Value = i;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (dataGridView1[1, i].Value.ToString() == "Found")
                    {
                        // dataGridView1[1, i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        dataGridView1[1, i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1[1, i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        // dataGridView1[2, i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
                label6.Text = "Checking Links Completed";
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Visible = true;
                button1.Visible = true;
            }


     static public String URLExists(string url)
            {
                String result = "Not Found";
               try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        response.Close();
                        result = "Found";
                        return result;
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                                 return result;
               }

                 return result;

            }
```

Comment: You put the code in BackgroundWorker and handle the results. Is there some specific problem with that?

Comment: An alternative is to start a thread updating the URLs status (found or not). In this case, you should either use a timer to update UI or start the thread at very beginning of the application and show status at end of other initialisations (_only if initialization process last more than n seconds_).

Comment: I dont know how to do those.Can you please edit my script and let me know how to implement as it will be very helpful for me :) Thanks for the reply

Comment: Any network operation on the main thread will block. You need to spawn a new thread to check your url, then update the ui with a delegate, as you can't update the ui thread (main) from a separate thread either.

Answer (score 0):

Some code where UI update is made in timer event.

```
private enum Status { Pending, FoundUnprocessed, FoundProcessed, NotFoundNotProcessed, NotFoundProcessed }
private List<Status>   URLStatuses = new List<bool>() ;
private List<string>   URLs        = new List<string>() ;


private void StartUrlsThreads()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(label2.Text); i++)
  {
     URLs.Add(dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString());
     URLStatuses.Add(false) ; 
     Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(URLExists));
     newThread.Start(URLs[i]) ;
  }
}

private void URLExists(object urlobj)
{
  try
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create((string)urlobj);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
       response.Close();
       URLStatuses[URLs.IndexOf((string)urlobj)]=Status.FoundUnprocessed ;
    }
    else URLStatuses[URLs.IndexOf((string)urlobj)]=Status.NotFoundUnprocessed ;
  }       
  catch { URLStatuses[URLs.IndexOf((string)urlobj)]=Status.NotFoundUnprocessed ; }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i=0;i<URLs.Count;i++) 
  {
    if (URLStatuses[i]==Status.FoundUnprocessed) 
    {
   URLStatuses[i]==Status.FoundProcessed ;
       // update DataGridView && progressbar
    }
    if (URLStatuses[i]==Status.NotFoundUnprocessed) 
    {
   URLStatuses[i]==Status.NotFoundProcessed ;
       // update DataGridView && progressbar
    }
// stop timer if no more pending status
}
```